# Microsoft Access front-end database updating all rows of data with the same entry when a single selection is made within a combobox

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox, frontend, backend

I inherited a database from my now retired boss that is acting a little weird. So the team who uses and asked for the database wanted two fields changed in our clients table. They wanted the AmendedDate --> InputDate & AmendedBy --> InputBy. So I changed them in the Backend while they were all out, and deleted/re-linked the Clients table to the front end and changed all references to match that change... I think.

We started it all up and the only problem is that when they make a selection in the InputBy field with the combo box on the front-end, every single one of the rows changes to match that selection. The Back end doesn't seem to reflect this error but I'm not sure how to stop this from happening. Please let me know if you need anything from me to help figure this out.

Here's a screenshot album to help paint the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/le6aB.jpg

Comment: Looks like the field got unbound during the changes, i.e. has no control source anymore. If that's not the case, please add the SQL of the record source of the form.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the issue, I'll have to wait to hear their testing results on this one. Shoulda caught that but it's been a bit stressful working on their active database.